# Setting up Azure WebJobs using ConfigureWebHostDefaults

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobssdk

The [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-get-started) uses the following code snipper to set up a WebJob.

```
var builder = new HostBuilder();
builder.ConfigureWebJobs(b =>
{
    b.AddAzureStorageCoreServices();
});
```

For some reason, I need to leverage `ConfigureWebHostDefaults` to set up http related HostServices (I want to be able to parse Razor templates for sending emails in the background).

```
var builder = new HostBuilder();
builder.ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webbuilder => webbuilder.UseStartup<Startup>())
builder.ConfigureWebJobs(b =>
{
    b.AddAzureStorageCoreServices();
});
```

I was wondering if leveraging `ConfigureWebHostDefaults` makes any problem or stability issue for the WebJob. I couldn't find even a sample which uses this method for setting up a WebJob. So, I'm in doubt if using it is a right thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

Using `ConfigureWebHostDefaults` creates a fair amount of boiler plate that's specifically for web hosts, see [here](https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/issues/2271#issuecomment-526744295). Instead of using Startup.cs, I would use `ConfigureServices` extension on `IHostBuilder`. I made [gist](https://gist.github.com/RyanHill-MSFT/066751d6ff18bded2b7b47d3056da485) you can look at.